# load all views at once in an activity

Tags: android, listadapter

[image]
I show an array of image views using a list adapter. I set their IDs in program dynamically. The problem is when I scroll the adapter to right, the images get their IDs only when they come on the screen. When I scroll to left again, the IDs of previous images are reset to  new value. How could I stop such a behavior and set the ID of all images at the start of activity launch?

The working is as shown in the diagram. The old image gets a new id, everytime it is brought into activity screen, which creates problems accessing it via old ID.
My image adapter code:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        final ImageView i = new ImageView(thView.getView().getContext());
        Bitmap bm;
        try {
            bm = thView.getBitmapFromAsset(lis.get(position));
            bm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, 100, 100, false);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            bm=null;
        }
        i.setImageBitmap(bm);
        final RelativeLayout borderImg = new RelativeLayout(thView.getView().getContext());

        i.setId(x);
        Log.w("ID set as",""+x);
        i.setTag(IMAGEVIEW_TAG);
        x++;
        borderImg.addView(i);           
         i.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                fname = lis.get(position);
                ClipData.Item item = new ClipData.Item((CharSequence) v
                        .getTag());
                dragData = new ClipData(
                        (CharSequence) v.getTag(),
                        new String[] { ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN },
                        item);

                View.DragShadowBuilder myShadow = new MyDragShadowBuilder(i);
                v.startDrag(dragData, myShadow, null, 0);
                return false;
            }
         });
         myDragEventListener mDragListen = new myDragEventListener();
         i.setOnDragListener(mDragListen);
        return borderImg;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure how the activity behave with scroll left and right. would you please make it simpler or include screenshots or code.

Comment: @Saifuddin The basic working of my image adapter.

Comment: @dmon Posted my adapter code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `x`? If `x` depends on the position, then why don't you use that instead, since you always have it?

You can't do what you want without really going around what an AdapterView means. Also, if you render all of your image views at the beginning, you might run into out of memory issues.

I guess the real question is what are you trying to accomplish with the ID?